# In Neo4j, can I set the node ID manually?

Tags: neo4j

When I create nodes and relationships, I want to set the id of node to differentiate the nodes so that I can use node id to match different edges or paths.

I don't know whether Neo4j supports this kind of operation. Until now, I've tried add id info in the node property.

Answer (score 0):

The native ID for an entity (node or relationship) is determined by the neo4j server, and you have no control over it. Also, you should be aware that a native ID can be reused after its original entity is deleted.

You should continue to create your own unique ID properties when you need to.